# SortByKey in JavaPairRDD is creating multiple jobs

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to sort within partition based on key in JavaPairRDD using keyComparator. I checked sortByKey it is creating two jobs within one spark submit one without shuffle(single stage:(mapToPair+sortByKey)) and another job with shuffle(two stages: mapToPair & sortByKey).

This looks completely unnecessary to have two jobs and I am not able to find way to do inpartition sort. Tried MapParititionsToPair doing

```
rdd.mapParititionsToPair(it -> //creating list and adding element from iterator list then sorting list)
```

is going out of memory. Please help here.